# Vue: How to dynamically update a list with a button click?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am currently studying the Vue framework with this [tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/6).
The current episode is about Computed Properties. I have two lists of tasks, one with all of them and one with only those that are incomplete. With a button click the second list should be updated so it only shows tasks that are completed instead. I also want the message "Incomplete tasks" to change to "Completed tasks!. But how do I do all this without hassle?

The clue I received in the tutorial was this console command: `app.tasks[0].completed = false;`

**HTML**

```
<div id="computedList">

    <h2>All Tasks</h2>

    <ul>    
        <li v-for="task in tasks" v-text="task.description"></li>

    </ul>

    <h2>{{ message }}</h2>

    <ul>
        <li v-for="task in incompleteTasks" v-text="task.description"></li>
    </ul>

    <button @click="toggleClass">Complete Class</button>

    <br>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var appb = new Vue({

    el: '#computedList',

    data: {
        message: 'Incomplete tasks',
        tasks: [
            {description: 'Begin to study Vue', completed: true},
            {description: 'Begin with the testapp', completed: true},
            {description: 'Begin to study the ABB webbapp', completed: false},
            {description: 'Begin to study Angular2', completed: false},
        ]
    },

    computed: {

        incompleteTasks() {

            return this.tasks.filter(task => !task.completed); //Filtrerar ovanstående lista!

        }
        },

    methods: {
        toggleClass() {
            return this.tasks.filter(task => task.completed);
        }
        },
});
```

I want the solution to contain as little code as possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main bit of changeable program state you describe is whether you're showing completed or incomplete tasks. You should have a `data` item for that.

```
showingCompleted: false
```

Your `message` can be computed from that (rather than being a `data` item), so in your `computed` section, you would have something like

```
message() {
  return this.showingCompleted ? 'Completed tasks' : 'Incomplete tasks';
}
```

The `toggleClass` method doesn't do what its name indicates. It should toggle `showingCompleted`:

```
this.showingCompleted = !this.showingCompleted;
```

Finally, your computed list of incomplete tasks should be based on `showingCompleted`, so that it can be either incomplete or completed tasks:

```
filteredTasks() {
  return this.tasks.filter(task => task.completed === this.showingCompleted);
}
```